# Wash sale rule with dividend reinvestment

Tags: united-states, dividends, dividend-reinvestment, wash-sale

Let's say I buy some stock. Two weeks later it pays a dividend which is reinvested in fractional shares of the stock. The next day I sell all shares at a loss. Would this be considered a wash sale? [This page](http://www.fairmark.com/capgain/wash/wsreplac.htm) suggests not, but I've found sources that say otherwise. If I had dividend reinvestment enabled but want to sell multiple positions soon, how can I avoid wash sale rules (other than not selling at a loss)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sold all shares? The potential wash sale effect goes away after 30 days from the dividend date. Selling all shares of a stock where a wash existed effectively negates the wash and you can take the loss.

Comment: Correct (or at least I will). See comment on littleadv's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find any authority for the opinion you suggest. Wash sale rules should, IMHO, apply.

[According to the regulations](http://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.1091-1), you attribute the newly purchased shares to the oldest sold shares for the purposes of the calculation of the disallowed loss and cost basis.

> **(c)** Where the amount of stock or securities acquired within the 61-day period is less than the amount of stock or securities sold or
>   otherwise disposed of, then the particular shares of stock or
>   securities the loss from the sale or other disposition of which is not
>   deductible shall be those with which the stock or securities acquired
>   are matched in accordance with the following rule: The stock or
>   securities acquired will be matched in accordance with the order of
>   their acquisition (beginning with the earliest acquisition) with an
>   equal number of the shares of stock or securities sold or otherwise
>   disposed of.

You can resort to the claim that you have not, in fact, entered into the contract within 30 days, but when you gave the instructions to reinvest dividends. I don't know if such a claim will hold, but to me it sounds reasonable. This is similar to the rules re short sales (in **(g)** there). In this case, wash sale rules will not apply (unless you instructed to reinvest dividends within the 30 days prior to the sale). But I'd ask a tax professional if such a claim would hold, talk to a EA/CPA licensed in your state.

Comment: He sold all shares. 31 days later, if he still has no stock, i.e. no new purchase, he's good to take the loss on those shares.

Comment: @Joe his problem is that after he sold all shares, he got dividend and got it reinvested. I.e.: 31 days later he still has some of the stocks (he doesn't want to sell it because the commission is too high for the amount).

Comment: "The next day I sell all shares" threw me off. It read to me as if no shares remained.

Comment: I haven't done anything yet, but the plan is to sell all shares last. As long as dividends don't get reinvested after the fact, which is a separate but related question [here](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/29508/is-it-possible-that-for-shares-to-be-reinvested-in-a-stock-you-already-sold), I should be fine right?